# Laravel (PHP) : get a result from arrays to multidimensional associative array

Tags: php, laravel

I have two arrays. I would like to create a multidimensional associative array that has a city name as the key and the suburb as the corresponding value. Here is my code:

```
 foreach($result['cities'] as $city)
        {
            foreach($result['suburbs'] as $suburb)
            {
                    if($city['id'] == $suburb['city_id'])
                    {
                        array_push($suburbs,  $suburb);
                        $citySuburb[$city['city_name']] = $suburbs;
                    }

            }
        }
      $result['cities_suburbs'] = $citySuburb;
```

My problem is my getting some suburbs under the wrong city name. Let me show you in the picture below

[image]

As you can see, bluffhill suburb is in both Kadoma and Harare..That's the problem.

Regards

Comment: Can you [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68225315/edit) the two arrays to your question?

Comment: That’s because you keep on pushing suburbs to your `$suburbs` array, but that does never get reset to empty again when the outer loop moves on to the next city … Remove the array_push, and just do `$citySuburb[$city['city_name']][] = $suburb;` instead.

Comment: (Or just `$result['cities_suburbs'][$city['city_name']][] = $suburb;` to begin with, no actual need for the extra “helper array” `$citySuburb` either.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
$suburbs = [];
foreach($result['cities'] as $city)
{
    foreach($result['suburbs'] as $suburb)
    {
        if($city['id'] == $suburb['city_id']){
            $suburbs[] = $citySuburb[$city['city_name']];
        }
    }
}
return $suburbs;
```

Comment: That will have no effect

Comment: @N69S why is that?

Comment: You completly changed how the code runs. it is equivalent to just `return $result['suburbs']` + from where did you pull a `return` ?

Comment: @brian could you dd the $suburbs in here ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset your `$suburbs` array to an empty one for each city

```
foreach($result['cities'] as $city) {
    $suburbs = [];
    foreach($result['suburbs'] as $suburb) {
        if($city['id'] == $suburb['city_id']) {
            array_push($suburbs,  $suburb);
            $citySuburb[$city['city_name']] = $suburbs;
        }
    }
}
```

or dont use intermediate array at all, (and the condition in the if statement should be irrelevant

```
foreach($result['cities'] as $city) {
    foreach($result['suburbs'] as $suburb) {
        if($city['id'] == $suburb['city_id'])
            $citySuburb[$city['city_name']][] = $suburb;
        }
    }
}
```